# Pandas: Drop duplicates in col[A] keeping row based on condition on col[B]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given the dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A','B','B'], 'col2': ['type1', 'type2', 'type1', 'type2', 'type1'] , 'hour': ['18:03:30','18:00:48', '18:13:46', '18:11:29', '18:06:31']  })
```

```py
col1 col2   hour
A   type1   18:03:30 # Drop this row as (A type1) already present
A   type2   18:00:48
A   type1   18:13:46 # keep this row as (A type1) already present.
B   type2   18:11:29
B   type1   18:06:31
```

I want to **drop duplicates** based on col1,col2.

eg.(row(0): A   type1, row(2): A   type1)

**keeping** only the row that has the **latest hour** eg.(18:13:46).

I tried using **groupby** to return subset based on col1, and **drop_duplicates** to drop the duplicate in col2. I need to find a way to pass the condition (latest hour)

example code:

```py
for key, grp in df.groupby('col1'):
  grp.drop_duplicates(subset='col2', keep="LATEST OF HOUR")
```

Expected outcome:

```py
col1 col2   hour
A   type1   18:03:30
A   type2   18:00:48
B   type2   18:11:29
B   type1   18:06:31
```

### EDIT adding context

my original dataframe is larger, the solution needs to work for also:

```py
col1 col2   other  hour
A   type1   h  18:03:30 # Drop this row as (A type1) already present
A   type2   ss 18:00:48
A   type1   ll 18:13:46 # keep this row as (A type1) already present
B   type2   mm 18:11:29
B   type1   jj 18:06:31
```

it would still need to drop the column based on the hour

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])` ?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])`?

Comment: How am I sure that df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']) will always drop the col with the LATEST time (type1   18:13:46 ) ?

Comment: you can use `sort_values`  on the same subset to sort the values in ascending order. then use drop_duplicates

Comment: ok, so i sort the 'hour' column , and then keep Last will aways keep the last by value of the sorted column even if it isn't the column immediately after like in my edit?

Comment: @anky_91 I think i solved it like this: df.sort_values('hour').drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'] , keep = 'last') sorting on the hour to and then dropping duplicates of the two columns

Comment: @David8 nice, you can post it as answer and accept it. Meanwhile I would strongly suggest you to have a deep look into the docs, they are gems ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following anky_91's comment I solved it like this:

```py
df.sort_values('hour').drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'] , keep = 'last')
```

This sorts based on the column 'hour' so that you are sure that keep='last' gets the last element

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'] , keep = 'last')
```

Comment: I probably simplified too much, what if I have another column that isn't the same, how do I force it to keep the last of col 'hour'?

Comment: By the way, your question is a little confusing. On the dataframe you state 'drop this row' and point to the row with latest time. Then in the explanation state that you want to keep the row with latest time! The code above keeps the last row of each type of 'col1' & 'col2'. If you want to keep the first, just change `keep` to `first`

Comment: `keep ='last'` will always retain the last value & in terms of time, last is the latest (unless the rows are sorted in descending order)

Comment: yeah I made a mistake. Cause i want to keep the last one.

Comment: Then you can use `keep ='last'`. This will retain the last occurrence.