# How to drop duplicated rows in data frame based on certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDfAh.jpg)

Our objective right now is to drop the duplicate player rows, but keep the row with the highest count in the G column (Games played). What code can we use to achieve this? I've attached a link to the image of our Pandas output here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Drop duplicates in col\[A\] keeping row based on condition on col\[B\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807305/pandas-drop-duplicates-in-cola-keeping-row-based-on-condition-on-colb)

Comment: add data a text not a picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop duplicates keeping the row with the highest value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459651/drop-duplicates-keeping-the-row-with-the-highest-value-in-another-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to first sort the dataframe by column G.

```py
df = df.sort_values(by='G', ascending=False)
```

You can then use drop_duplicates to drop all duplicates except for the first occurrence.

```py
df.drop_duplicates(['Player'], keep='first')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that I can think of

```
df.groupby('Player', as_index=False)['G'].max()
```

and

```
df.sort_values('G').drop_duplicates(['Player'] , keep = 'last')
```

The first method uses groupby to group values by Player, and contracts rows keeping the one with the maximum of G. The second one uses the drop_duplicate method of Pandas to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Assume your dataframe object is `df1` then

```
series= df1.groupby('Player')['G'].max() # this will return series.
pd.DataFrame(series)
```

let me know if this work for you or  not.